# dynamic, custom layout UICollectionView embedded in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have UITableViewController with 1 section and header with UISegmentedControl inside.

[If user presses first segment we should display UITableView cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWkvd.png)

[If user presses second segment we should display custom vertical scrolling collection grid with collection items below that header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMJm.png)

**possible solutions**:

1. change UITableViewController to UICollectionViewController, and UITableViewCells to UICollectionViewCells. This should work but I'm trying to avoid this solution
2. UICollectionView embedded in UITableViewCell. Setting UICollectionView scrolling enabled to false, adjusting UITableViewCell's height to fit entire UICollectionView's contentSize.height. In systemLayoutSizeFitting(...) method of container (UITableViewCell) we call layoutIfNeeded on container and on contained UICollectionView and return UICollectionView's contentSize.

   problem:

   (re)calculation of entire UICollectionView contentSize requires a lot of work if we have hundreds of items (cellForItemAtIndexPath for every item). Want to avoid this somehow. Maybe we can increase container (UITableViewCell) height during scrolling UICollectionView which is embedded inside.
3. Same as 2 but we have fixed size container UITableViewCell (same height as view without header) with UICollectionView inside. When we scroll UITableView to the very bottom UICollectionView scroll should continue scrolling.

   problem:

   I don't understand how to deal with 2 instances of UIScrollView with scrollingEnabled = true for both. I think this could be solved with pan gesture recognizer delegates. If it is so I need help here.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally opt for number 1 and completely avoid number 2. For number 3, you could set `tableView.scrollingEnabled = false` when the second segment is tapped. Set it to `true` when the first segment is tapped. That way, when it's `false`, the `UICollectionView` in your `UITableViewCell` can still scroll.

[This tutorial](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) may help with putting a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I'm searching for universal solution. 1 is not really universal. Imagine that UITableViewController is managing its child view controllers that are embedded dynamically into container UITableViewCell. They can be UITableViewController, UICollectionViewControllers or just regular UIViewControllers.

Comment: for 3. scrolling gesture should be delegated somehow from outer to inner scroll view when outer is scrolled to the bottom. and upside-down for opposite scrolling direction.

Comment: I've read Ash's article but it is not relevant to my problem because UICollectionView that is embedded in UITableViewCell should have vertical scrolling